# Array of arrays into array of hashes

Tags: ruby

i want to convert  in ruby

```
[[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1]]
```

into

`[{1=>1}, {2=>3}, {3=>5}, {4=>1}, {1=>2}, {2=>3}, {3=>5}, {4=>1}]`

and after this to obtain sum of all different keys:

```
{1=>3,2=>6,3=>10,4=>2}
```

Comment: do you need the second step or just want to achieve the last step

Comment: no , the second step was just to make task more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question

```
sum = Hash.new(0)
original_array.each{|x, y| sum[x] += y}
sum # => {1 => 3, 2 => 6, 3 => 10, 4 => 2}
```

Comment: Unless I know I'm the only user of the hash, I don't like doing things like this, it returns a hash which behaves in ways most people aren't expecting. e.g. it's standard practice to check existence with `Hash#[]`, and this will then return a truthy value.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek That is not the standard way to check existence. That will fail when you have nil values. The standard way is to use Hash#key?, and my code works well with it.

Comment: The ratio in which I have seen `Hash#[]` to `Hash#key?` is probably on the order of 25:1, and that only because I'm grouping `Hash#has_key?` in with it. In those cases, it was used because `false` was a legitimate hash value (or the hash contents weren't known). Personally, as soon as I use a default value or block, I stop thinking of it as a hash and start thinking of it as an interface (which I occasionally replace later with a custom object).

Answer (score 2):

Functional approach:

```
xs = [[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1]]    
Hash[xs.group_by(&:first).map do |k, pairs| 
  [k, pairs.map { |x, y| y }.inject(:+)]
end]
#=> {1=>3, 2=>6, 3=>10, 4=>2}
```

Using [Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/) is much simpler thanks to the abstractions `map_by` (a variation of `group_by`) and `mash` (`map` + `Hash`):

```
require 'facets'
xs.map_by { |k, v| [k, v] }.mash { |k, vs| [k, vs.inject(:+)] }
#=> {1=>3, 2=>6, 3=>10, 4=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the intermediate form.

```
arrays = [[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1]]

aggregate = arrays.each_with_object Hash.new do |(key, value), hash|
  hash[key] = hash.fetch(key, 0) + value
end

aggregate # => {1=>3, 2=>6, 3=>10, 4=>2}
```

Comment: Hmm. My first questions as a Java developer, does this involve any form of virgin sacrifice, or does it work out of the box?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood not really sure what you mean. If you'd like I can explain anything that isn't apparent.

Comment: @Joshua Cheek - It does look like magic to me at first glance, but having stared at it for a while it's beginning to make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr= [[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 1]]

final = Hash.new(0)

second_step = arr.inject([]) do |arr,inner|
   arr << Hash[*inner]
   final[inner.first] += inner.last
   arr
end

second_step
#=> [{1=>1}, {2=>3}, {3=>5}, {4=>1}, {1=>2}, {2=>3}, {3=>5}, {4=>1}] 
final
#=> {1=>3, 2=>6, 3=>10, 4=>2}
```

if you directly only need the last step

```
arr.inject(Hash.new(0)){|hash,inner| hash[inner.first] += inner.last;hash}
=> {1=>3, 2=>6, 3=>10, 4=>2}
```